# Creating Azure container registry in existing resource group with template

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I try to create an Azure container registry with a template. And I want to create the container registry in the resource group internet-suite.

I try it like this:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "containerRegistry1",
            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries",
            "apiVersion": "2019-05-01",
            "location": "West Europe",            
            "sku": {
                "name": "Basic"
            },
            "properties": {
                "adminUserEnabled": true
            }
        },

        {
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "nestedDeployment",
      "resourceGroup": "internet-suite",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "template": {
          resource-group-resources
        }
      }
    }

    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

But I get this error:

> Member name should be a string in double quotes.arm-template (syntax)

Comment: probably this need double quotes: ` resource-group-resources`.

Comment: Not sure what this second resource is for ? is you resource group already exist you dontneed to do anything

Comment: To create a container registry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***We have tried the same to create a Container registry with the given template by some modification and it works***;

*Here is the workaround*,

*And getting the similar issue  at `resource-group-resources` that need to add between double quotes as suggested the same by@*Thomas* as well .To resolve this we have tried to deploy to our existing resource group using [**`New-AzResourceGroupDeployment`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azresourcegroupdeployment?view=azps-8.1.0#description) by modifying your code and it works.*

***ERROR DETIALS:-***

[image]

***Modified Template:-***
**`some.json file`**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "name": "myacr",
            "type": "Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries",
            "apiVersion": "2019-05-01",
            "location": "West Europe",            
            "sku": {
                "name": "Basic"
            },
            "properties": {
                "adminUserEnabled": true
            }
        }

    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

***OUTPUT DETAILS:-***
[image]
[image]

*For more information please refer this* **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**| [***Microsoft.ContainerRegistry registries***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerregistry/registries?tabs=json)